# VisualStudio не собирает то, что собрал GCC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, компиляция

Есть простой класс для операци с переменными под мьютексом:

файл GSV.h

```
/* Global Secured Variable */
#ifndef GSV_H
#define GSV_H
#include <mutex>
template <typename T>
class GSV{
    T value;
    std::mutex m_value;
public:
    GSV(){}
    GSV(T val){value = val;}
    ~GSV(){}
    operator T(){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_value);
        return value;
    }
    operator=(T val){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_value);
        value = val;
    }
};
#endif /* GSV_H */
```

MSVS ругается так:

> Compiler error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed

на строку `operator=(T val){`

MinGW-w64 собирает без проблем и возмущений. Мне надо собрать проект в MSVS. Что ей не так, этой майкрософтовской среде?

[image: Versions]

Comment: объявление метода без возвращаемого типа это ошибка. Добавьте `void operator=(...)`

Comment: "Не так" именно в кривом "MinGW-w64" и в вашем коде. Старайтесь указывать флаги типа `-pedantic`, чтобы MinGW-w64 более-менее нормально рапортовал диагностические сообщения, требуемые стандартом языка.

Comment: А что у вас выдает `g++ --version`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, версии добавил в тему

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы объявляете функцию `operator=`, которая возвращает - что? Укажите возвращаемый тип, и все будет в порядке...

Обычно (но не обязательно) это ссылка на сам тип класса, а возвращается `*this`, чтоб можно было выполнять цепочки присваиваний типа `a = b = c;`.

Comment: Странно, GCC это не смущает и оно работает... Ну да ладно, это помогло. Спасибо!

Comment: @Iceman: Не смущает? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cdfc4eb46030572 Что у вас за  GCC такой? В GCC много дыр, но я не верю, чтобы он мог пропустить *такое*.

Comment: @AnT, смущает конечно, но да, пропускает и работает. Не работает, как оказалось, конструкция типа `a = b = c;`, как верно подметил Harry, за что ему спасибо. Версии средств добавил в тему

Comment: MinGW gcc плохо ругается, это факт, собирая то же самое под линуксом ошибок находит сразу и больше, чего то там ему обрезали, можно в ручную все флаги проверок прописать, тогда помогает, но не полностью :) например на инициализаторы типа `{0}` не реагирует в педантик моде.

Comment: @NewView А что не так с `{0}`?

Comment: `struct stat st = {0};` у вас ничего не говорит? Например

Comment: @NewView: А что оно должно говорить? В чем вы тут видите проблему?

Comment: не знаю как у других, у меня пишет `warning: missing initializer`, правильный вид, описывать всю структуру в инициализаторе, вроде этого: `struct stat st = {0,0,0U,0U...итд};`